# Google AutoML video classification batch prediction on custom model via Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We've trained a model using Google's AutoML video classification and now trying to make batch predictions via cloud function, we are currently using the following code but it returns the error message:

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details:
7 PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

following is the nodejs code:

```
exports.myFunction = (req, res) => {

  const projectId = 'project-id';
  const location = 'us-central1';
  const modelId = 'model-id';
  const inputUri = 'bucket-uri';
  const outputUri = 'bucket-uri';

  console.log("importing google cloud automl...");

  // Imports the Google Cloud AutoML library
  const {PredictionServiceClient} = require(`@google-cloud/automl`).v1;

  console.log("instantiating PredictionServiceClient...");

  // Instantiates a client
  const client = new PredictionServiceClient();

  console.log("instantiated PredictionServiceClient...");

  async function batchPredict() {
    // Construct request
    const request = {
      name: client.modelPath(projectId, location, modelId),
      inputConfig: {
        gcsSource: {
          inputUris: [inputUri],
        },
      },
      outputConfig: {
        gcsDestination: {
          outputUriPrefix: outputUri,
        },
      },
    };

    console.log("making batch prediction...");
    const [operation] = await client.batchPredict(request);

    console.log("about to run promise...");
    const [response] = await operation.promise();
    console.log(response);

    res.status(200).send("Prediction successfull!");
  }

  // make prediction
  batchPredict();

};
```

Comment: What roles have you assigned to the service account for Cloud Functions? You have a permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 
"const client = new PredictionServiceClient();"
then the default service account is used for the process.
"service-@gcp-sa-automl.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

The following permissions are required to run the batch prediction:

1. AutoML Admin
2. AutoML Predictor
3. AutoML Service Agent
4. Storage Object Admin

If you want to use different service account use the below code.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/path/to/service-account-key.json")
const client = new PredictionServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
```